# Read JSON field in athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, hiveql, amazon-athena

column value
`[[1652336534,860,0],[1652343704,51,0],[1652345322,24,0],[1652349754,70,0]]`

how to read this in Athena. what data type need to declare for column to read this type of json array.

Comment: @cosbor11 pls help me into this.

Comment: @Ilya Kisil could you please help me into this.

Comment: Looks like `array(array(integer))` to me

Comment: you can use **array<string>** but array subscript will be in index 0 as whole.

Answer (score 0):

If your data stored in S3, you can create the table like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tablename (
fieldname array<array<string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://athena-testbucket/'
```

Query should be like:

```
select fieldname[1][1] from test
```

Note: The indices of the array in Athena start at 1.